# How to read file contents

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, plist

I have a text view on which i m droping a plist file. It's displaying the path of the file which i dropped there. Now i want to read the contents of that file without opening the file. How to do that? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Have a look at the [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSMutableDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes and the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html).

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Then you manipulate the dictionary and display (some of) its content in something like [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

---

> "Now i want to read the contents of that file without opening the file"

I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. To read the content of a file, you have to open the file.

Comment: what i mean by not opening is that i don't want user to see the contents of that file. User just drag that file on the text view, depending upon that i want to read contents of that file and do some manipulation of it's key values.

Comment: That is quite helpful. But how get path of the file from text view?

Comment: see drag&drop documentation at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html

Answer (score 0):

Impossible!
You have to open a file in order to read its content - either explicitely or implicitely (e.g. a module/command does it for you)!

Comment: what i mean by not opening is that i don't want user to see the contents of that file. User just drag that file on the text view, depending upon that i want to read contents of that file and do some manipulation of it's key values.